# TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

Tags: python

i am trying to store some output from my pycharm project to a different file, but i keep recieving this Error "  File "C:/Users/maher/PycharmProjects/CashRegistry/venv/CashRegistry.py", line 40, in Bill
f.write(info[0], "\t", info[1], "\t\t\t $" + str(info[2]))
TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (4 given)" , here is my code:

```
with open('SaleReport.txt', 'w+') as f:

    f.write("""\nReport of Sales:
    Item:\tQuantity\tSales""")
    for info in quantity:
        f.write(info[0], "\t", info[1], "\t\t\t $" + str(info[2]))
```

Comment: The error is pretty darn clear…!? You're passing 4 separate arguments to `write`. You need to concatenate them into one string using `+` for example, or call `write` multiple times with one argument each.

Comment: `write` is not like `print`; you can't pass an arbitrary number of arguments and have `write` combine them into a single string for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `File "C:/Users/maher/PycharmProjects/CashRegistry/venv/CashRegistry.py" Line 40`

from

```
f.write(info[0], "\t", info[1], "\t\t\t $" + str(info[2]))
```

to :

```
f.write(f'{info[0]}\t{info[1]}\t\t\t ${info[2]})
```